# module Bcrypt.Base is not available

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've been playing around with Elixir and I've not been able to fix this issue despite trying numerous times.

I've installed and compiled Bycrypt module and "module Bcrypt.Base is not available" error.

Here is my encrypt method on user.ex file:

```
  defp encrypt_password(changeset) do
    if changeset.valid? do
      changeset
      |> put_change(:password_hash, Bcrypt.hash_pwd_salt(changeset.changes.password))
    else
      changeset
    end
  end
```

Here is the error:

```
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST //api/v1/users
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Bcrypt.Base.gensalt_nif/3 is undefined (module Bcrypt.Base is not available)
        (bcrypt_elixir) Bcrypt.Base.gensalt_nif(<<173, 70, 166, 223, 71, 67, 148, 239, 134, 39, 160, 5, 39, 96, 163, 253>>, 12, 98)
        (bcrypt_elixir) lib/bcrypt.ex:86: Bcrypt.hash_pwd_salt/2
        (portal_api) web/models/user.ex:285: PortalApi.User.encrypt_password/1
        (portal_api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:204: PortalApi.UserController.create_user/3
        (portal_api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: PortalApi.UserController.action/2
        (portal_api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: PortalApi.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:288: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
        (portal_api) lib/plug/error_handler.ex:64: PortalApi.Router.call/2
        (portal_api) lib/portal_api/endpoint.ex:1: PortalApi.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (portal_api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: PortalApi.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (portal_api) lib/portal_api/endpoint.ex:1: PortalApi.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug_cowboy) lib/plug/cowboy/handler.ex:18: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) c:/laragon/www/wirecrafters/portal-api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

This is my deps in mix.exs file:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.3"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2.2"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.13"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2.1", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "0.13.1"},
      {:junit_formatter, ">= 2.0.0"},
      {:comeonin, "~> 5.3"},
      {:remix, "~> 0.0.1", only: :dev},
      {:ex_machina, "~> 1.0"},
      {:ja_serializer, ">= 0.12.0"},
      {:guardian, "~> 1.2"},
      {:faker, "~> 0.7"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.1"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
      {:corsica, "~> 0.5"},
      {:timex, "~> 3.0"},
      {:timex_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
      {:canary, "~>1.1.0"},
      {:credo, "~> 0.8", only: [:dev, :test]},
      {:bamboo, "~> 1.2.0"},
      {:bamboo_smtp, "~> 1.7.0"},
      {:arc, "~> 0.11"},
      {:arc_ecto, "~> 0.11"},
      {:ex_aws, "~> 2.1"},
      {:ex_aws_s3, "~> 2.0"},
      {:hackney, "~> 1.15"},
      {:poison, "~> 2.1"},
      {:sweet_xml, "~> 0.6"},
      {:secure_random, "~> 0.5"},
      {:floki, "~> 0.17.0"},
      {:bugsnex, "~> 0.4.1"},
      {:temp, "~> 0.4"},
      {:csv, "~> 2.1.1"},
      {:scrivener_ecto, "~> 1.0"},
      {:quantum, ">= 2.2.7"},
      {:elixir_uuid, "~> 1.2"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.1"},
      {:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 1.0"}
    ]
  end
```

Is there something I'm missing? Any ideas how I can get it to work?
Thank you,

Comment: Looks like you're on windows, here is a [similar issue](https://github.com/riverrun/bcrypt_elixir/issues/11#issuecomment-482797136), did you follow [this guide](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/wiki/Requirements#windows)?

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your problem if I use your `deps` in a mix project. Nor if I load the dependency with `Mix.install` and make the same call:

```
iex(1)> Mix.install([{:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 1.0"}])
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
New:
  bcrypt_elixir 1.1.1
  elixir_make 0.6.2
* Getting bcrypt_elixir (Hex package)
* Getting elixir_make (Hex package)
...
Generated bcrypt_elixir app
:ok
iex(2)> Bcrypt.hash_pwd_salt("test")
"$2b$12$xzg3mp9AJQvz9mDZxoHDNerHUXXH1MX6BI6q.VE0uf6Ake/MM7v62"
```

How are you starting your app? It seems most likely that you have not done `mix deps.get`, or somehow have not fetched or deployed the dependency correctly.